# Repaint over a pink bike

Tags: paint

My son is now 6 years old and has outgrown his small bike. There is a bike available from his elder sister but it is pink colour. This pink bike might work for him for a year or two before he outgrows it, but he might want an other colour.

I am wondering if there is a simple way for me to paint it over with a red or black colour without removing the existing paint ? I would like to keep it on the cheap side, around 10 or 20$.

Comment: Clean it and ruff it up a bit with 600 sand paper.  Use like a flat black to help hide runs.  Use a couple light coats over a heavy coat.

Comment: and do u know if we are talking of 10 to 20 bucks or better to get a new bike..thx a lot for the reply

Comment: A can of spray paint is only like $7   It will not be a new bike or even close to new bike paint job but it will be black.

Comment: What Blam said -- you need to "rough it up" a bit with sandpaper (I'd use something a hair coarser than 600 grit), then repaint either with a brush or with spray paint.  Or you can go to an auto parts place and buy a "primer", instead of sanding.  In either case, be sure to wash the bike first, and use up most of a roll of masking tape, masking off the stuff that should not be painted.

Comment: (But if you look around, used bikes are often available quite cheaply, or sometimes for given away for free, out of a neighbor's shed or garage where it's been collecting dust for years.)

Comment: Some communities have bike swaps, or it might be the kind of thing that would be great to organize at your son's school (or maybe see if one of the older classes would like to do it as a service project).

Comment: Tell him that pink bikes are what the Giro winners ride while wearing a pink jersey. ;-)

Comment: thx Carel ! -;) I think , he is ok, I have convinced him and personally do not mind him riding a pink bike, its just that at so small an age I do not want other kids to be teasing him ....and I tihnk that could happen...

Answer (score 2):

Use this as an opportunity to teach him how to paint. Yes, you'll do much of the work, but you two can work together to pre-sand the existing paint, mask the parts you're not painting, and spray the new paint on.

Comment: thx...I like the thought...spending some time togather...-:)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use PlastiDip or something similar. It's not paint it's some kind of rubber coating, but I hear that it's really easy to spray on, gives a good finish (with a few applications) and doesn't require a lot of preparation (no sanding, it's removed easily if you spray at the wrong place). A lot of people use these products for car parts.